# OnPropertyChanged no compatible code running

Tags: c#, xamarin

I have a bluetooth module from which i fetch some data. When the value of the characteristic is being updated, an event is being raised, which I subscribe to in my Viewmodel. Unfortunately, my Viewmodel doesn't update the values that I'm getting from my characteristic.

```
public class viewModel
{   
    ViewModel
    {
        bluetoothDevice.PropertyChanged += (s, e) =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Test: " + e.PropertyName); //correctly updates
            CurrentValue = e.PropertyName;
        };
    }
    public string CurrentValue 
    {
        get
        {
            return _currentValue;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_currentValue!= value)
            {
                _currentValue= value;
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(_currentValue));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

From my `Console.WriteLine` Its correctly writing the value updates.

If I however put a breakpoint in my `PropertyChanged?` update, I get an error saying:

> No compatible code running" - "The selected debug engine does not support any code executing on the current thread (e.g. only native runtime code is executing)

Comment: Already tried :-(

Comment: are you updating the property on the UI thread? what xamarin is this, is it forms?

Comment: It is forms yes, and i'm not updating it on the UI Thread,

Comment: @thumbmunkeys How exactly will it make a difference? Until and unless he is trying to show that on the UI? FYI I genuinely don't know

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update the property on the ui thread:

```
Xamarin.Forms.Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(()=> viewModel.CurrentValue = "Hello");
```

Comment: Thats great - That solved the exception. but my setter is not updating the binding in my view.

Comment: @Avacay you'd need to post the view code and the binding to analyze that